# Word 2007: Dynamic Summary List of Checkboxes

Tags: ms-word, office-2007

I am currently writing a User Guide using Word 2007 where each section has some validation checkboxes to help the consumer implement the solution and track his progress.

I have been able to create Word Checkboxes that can be clicked on using Developper>Legacy Tools>Checkboxes and then Protecting the Document to only allow "Filling in forms".

The next problem is that we want to provide a summary of all the checkboxes in the document in one aggregate list and that it be dynamic (ie: when a checkbox is checked, it also checks it in the summary list).

Is this possible to accomplish ?

**TL;DR:**

1. How do I create a summary list of all checkboxes?
2. How do I control one document from another with ActiveX Controls?